# Error while relocating binary code (gcc -> objdata -> load binary code -> and execute)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, shared-objects, objcopy

I'm implementing a genetic algorithm, the creatures are functions that have three pointers as input and output.
All have the form:

```
// No need for global variables

void _start (float *i, float *o, float *m)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

The creatures should be a few thousand, and very small, so I decided not to use shared objects but simply load raw code and run it.

The creatures are compiled

```
gcc -O3 -c code.c
```

then I take the code of the function in this way

```
objcopy -O binary --only-section=.text code.o rawcode
```

and then load the code into memory and run it

```
((void(*)(void*,void*,void*)) loaded_code) (i, o, m);
```

This work until in the source code **there aren't floating-point literals**, for example the code:

```
void _start (int *i, int *o, int *m)
{
    i[0] = m[0] + m[1];
}
```

Compilated produces this working code:

```
gcc -O3 -c code.c
objdump -d code.o

code.o:     formato del file elf64-x86-64


Disassemblamento della sezione .text:

0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   f3 0f 10 02             movss  (%rdx),%xmm0
   4:   f3 0f 58 42 04          addss  0x4(%rdx),%xmm0
   9:   f3 0f 11 07             movss  %xmm0,(%rdi)
   d:   c3                      retq
```

But a function with floating-point literal as:

```
void _start (float *i, float *o, float *m)
{
    i[0] = m[0] + 3.0f;
}
```

Produces a code that when executed doesn't give the correct result

```
gcc -O3 -c code.c
objdump -d code.o

code.o:     formato del file elf64-x86-64


Disassemblamento della sezione .text:

0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   f3 0f 10 05 00 00 00    movss  0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 8 <_start+0x8>
   7:   00 
   8:   f3 0f 58 02             addss  (%rdx),%xmm0
   c:   f3 0f 11 07             movss  %xmm0,(%rdi)
  10:   c3                      retq
```

And this happens every time that a instruction is generated using **%rip**.
How do I setting gcc to not generate this code? In theory, to insert a floating-point constant can be done as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514537/how-do-i-specify-immediate-floating-point-numbers-with-inline-assembly) or not?

You have any suggestion to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler puts the constants into the `.rodata` section which you don't even copy, so it isn't just a relocation problem. You could use a custom linker script that merges and relocates the code as necessary instead of `objcopy`, as follows:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)

SECTIONS
{
    merged : {
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata)
    } = 0x90

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(*) /* discard everything else */
    }
}
```

Not sure why you wanted to avoid shared objects, that would be the simplest solution. You could just `dlopen` them and don't bother with the details.

Comment: Thanks it works! I wanted to avoid shared objects because it seems bad load thousands of .so for functions such small, and because I'm doing it as a hobby