# Clang doesn't pass value via register as the code specified

Tags: c, x86-64, inline-assembly, calling-convention

I have the below snippet of code, and here I want to pass the value of variable `num` by register *rax*, but it seems in the assembly code, clang doesn't use rax directly. Rather, it saves the value of `num` on the stack and then passes the value on the stack to the `rsi` register which the behavior is different from GCC. Why? BTW, I didn't use any optimization flags in the compilation command.

**C Code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  register long num asm("rax") = 0x100000000;
  printf("%ld\n", num);
  return 0;
}
```

**Assembly Code (Clang)**:

```
main:                                   # @main
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
        movabsq $4294967296, %rax               # imm = 0x100000000
        movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
        movq    -16(%rbp), %rsi  # <- here, for calling printf, the parameter is not passed directly from register, -
                                 # but indirectly from a stack location. Why?
        movabsq $.L.str, %rdi
        movb    $0, %al
        callq   printf
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $16, %rsp
        popq    %rbp
        retq
.L.str:
        .asciz  "%ld\n"
```

**Assembly Code (GCC)**:

```
.LC0:
        .string "%ld\n"
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movabsq $4294967296, %rax
        movq    %rax, %rsi    # <-
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why? BTW, I didn't use any optimization flags in the compilation command.

Without optimization, compiler is free to generate suboptimal code with extra moves.

With `-O2` `clang-11` produces nearly exactly the same code as GCC:

```
        pushq   %rax
        movabsq $4294967296, %rsi               # imm = 0x100000000
        movl    $.L.str, %edi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        callq   printf
...
```

Comment: But in this case, the rax is not used for storing the value 0x100000000 here.

Comment: Becavalier, You don't use `num` in any inline assembly statements, so the compiler has no reason to load the value into eax.

Answer (score 1):

**`register ... asm("regname")` GNU C explicit-register variables

don't break or affect the calling convention in any way.**

As documented [in the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html), the only guaranteed behaviour is for operands to extended asm statements like `asm("..." : "=r"(var))`, forcing which reg `"r"` picks.

It doesn't make callers pass args in the wrong registers to function calls.

**Any behaviour other than around an `asm` statement is just an implementation detail.**  (GCC used to document stronger behaviour, but they decided to undocument = unsupport stuff other than this.  The actual behaviour was never calling-convention breaking.)

e.g. Un-optimized `clang` output does happen to materialize the value in RAX, and it's still there when calling `printf` because its low byte is `0`, and clang only merged a `0` (number of args in XMM regs) into the low byte of RAX (AL), unlike GCC avoiding false dependencies by zeroing the whole RAX.

---

#### Other ways of getting a custom calling convention for a single function call:

**None that I know of**, unless the convention you want is one of the one the compiler already knows.  e.g. you can put `__attribute__((ms_abi))` or `__attribute__((sysv_abi))` on a function prototype.

Other than that, you *can* in theory put a `call` instruction in an inline-asm statement, but only if you adjust RSP around it to avoid stepping on the red-zone, and declare clobbers on every call-clobbered register (including integer, MMX, x87, and zmm0..31 and k0..7 or ymm0..15, MPX bnd0..3, maybe that's all for now.  And of course `"memory"`).  Or read-write or matching-constraint operands for arg-passing registers.  This is highly not recommended, and a huge pain.

See also these Q&As for examples, but really it would be best to avoid this if you can:

- [In Clang/LLVM x86-64 inline assembly, how do I say I clobbered the x87/media state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774687/in-clang-llvm-x86-64-inline-assembly-how-do-i-say-i-clobbered-the-x87-media-sta)
- [Calling printf in extended inline ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502841/calling-printf-in-extended-inline-asm)