# Express floating point constant from EQU symbolic name

Tags: assembly, syntax, floating-point, arm, ds-5

I'm programming in ARM assembly in DS-5 5.28, targetting cortex-a8 with floating point and Neon.

When expressing constants with EQU, like

```
M EQU 5
```

then I can use the constant in the rest of the program, in particular when allocating constants in data memory like e.g:

```
mydata  DCD  M
```

Now, if I want to allocate a floating point constant as 32-bit binary, I can do:

```
myfloat  DCFS  5
```

or indifferently:

```
myfloat  DCFS  5.0
```

But the following gives syntax error:

```
myfloat  DCFS  M
```

I've tried all sort of tricks like `DCFS (M+0.0)` or `M EQU 5.0`, but nothing is accepted by the assembler, and I can't find directives to cast constants, and not even an Arm forum that seems suitable. Nor I'd like to hard-code constants (that may change) more than once in the code.

**EDIT 1**

I've tried with macros, same error (A1194E: Bad floating-point number):

```
    MACRO
$label  FP_CONSTANT  $value
$label  DCFS    $value
    MEND

; use:
myfloat  FP_CONSTANT  M
```

I would like to check if I wrote it correctly by disassembling the result, but compilation fails so there's no object to disassemble.

Comment: Yeah, I see.  That's not what I mean with “use a macro,” but it seems like the assembler doesn't support the kind of macros I was thinking about anyway.

Comment: If you mean C-like macros, that's what I was actually looking for, but I did not found anything [see here for example](https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/compilers/arm-compiler-5/docs/dui0473/latest/directives-reference)

Comment: For GNU GAS, I would recommend using the C preprocessor for macros, since GAS preprocessing is just too weak. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514537/how-do-i-specify-immediate-floating-point-numbers-with-inline-assembly/52906126#52906126 but `.equ asdf, #1.5` refuses to work for that syntax and any variant I've tried on AS 2.31.

Answer (score 1):

The `EQU` directive defines a symbol to take a specific value.  Symbol values are addresses which are in turn integers.  You can't give a symbol a floating point number as a value.

As an alternative, read the manual of your assembler.  Most assemblers have the capability to define *macros* which should allow you to give a symbolic name to a floating point constant by defining it as a macro.

Comment: I've read the manual deeply, I think I don't deserve "RTFM" replies. I did not think of macros, I'll check but I'm a little bit skeptic because the problem seems you cannot define a floating point constant from an integer one. Something like C's #define would be needed, more like a low-level textual substitution.

Comment: @m.alessandrini Macros are essentially that low-level textual substitution. I referred you to the manual because I am not familiar with your assembler, so it's probably easier if you look up how to use macros on your own then have me guess what the syntax is.

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry for the misunderstanding. Unfortunately I've tried with macros (useful knowledge anyway) but it raises the same error after macro expansion: Bad floating-point number

Comment: @m.alessandrini Could you add the code with macros to your question so I can understand what exactly you wrote?