# Questions on atomic_add function of arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, atomic, inline-assembly, arm64

I am very new to Linux Kernel-based C-coding Style. I am trying to understand the following implementation of the "atomic_add" function from "arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h" file (Lines 112-124 of [here](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/tegra/+/android-7.1.1_r0.53/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h)).

```c
static inline void atomic_add(int i, atomic_t *v)
{ 
    unsigned long tmp;
    int result;
    asm volatile("// atomic_add\n"
        "1: ldxr    %w0, %2\n"
        "   add %w0, %w0, %w3\n"
        "   stxr    %w1, %w0, %2\n"
        "   cbnz    %w1, 1b"
        : "=&r" (result), "=&r" (tmp), "+Q" (v->counter)
        : "Ir" (I));

}
```

Please help me to understand the following questions.

1. What is the meaning of %w0 or %w3? I understand that %2 is referring to the counter value.
2. Is %w0 referring to the (result) variable or a general-purpose register?
3. Does the constraint string "Ir" stand for "Immediate Register"?

Comment: `%0` refers to the first parameter.  The `w` is a modifier.  There's some discussion of the arm modifiers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960240/armv8-floating-point-output-inline-assembly/54031233#comment94948720_54031233).  In particular, you might find the link to [armclang](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100067/0610/armclang-Inline-Assembler/Inline-assembly-template-modifiers) useful.  "Ir" are constraints and are doc'ed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `w` is an *operand modifier*.  It causes the inline asm to contain the 32-bit name of the register (`w0`, etc) instead of its 64-bit name (`x0`) which would be the default.  See the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AArch64-Operand-Modifiers).  (This feature was undocumented in gcc 13 and earlier, but has been supported in practice for a long time, for compatibility with [armclang](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100067/0610/armclang-Inline-Assembler/Inline-assembly-template-modifiers).)  You can also [try it](https://godbolt.org/z/df14qTa1d) and note that if you write `%0` instead of `%w0`, the generated instruction uses the 64-bit `x` register.  That is not what you would want since these should be 32-bit loads and stores.
2. Both.  As usual for GCC-style extended asm, `%w0` refers to operand number 0 of the inline asm (with, as mentioned, the `w` modifier to use its 32-bit name).  Here that is the one declared with `"=&r" (result)`.  Since the constraint is `r`, this operand will be allocated a general-purpose register, and all mentions of `%0` (respectively `%w0`) in the asm code will be replaced with the name of that register.  In the Godbolt example above, the compiler chose `x9` (respectively `w9`).

   The `(result)` means that after the asm statement, the compiler should take whatever is left in `w9` and store it in the variable `result`.  It could do this with a store to memory, or a `mov` to whatever register is being used for `result`, or it could just allocate `result` in that variable itself.  With luck, the optimizer should choose the latter; and since `result` isn't used for anything after the `asm`, it should not do anything further with that register.  So in effect, an output operand with a variable that isn't used afterwards is a way of telling the compiler "please pick a register that I can use as scratch".
3. This is two constraints, `I` and `r`.  Constraints are documented by GCC: [simple](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html) and [machine-specific](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints), and when multiple constraints are given, the compiler can choose to satisfy any one of them.

   `I` asks for an immediate value suitable for use in an AArch64 `add` instruction, i.e. a 12-bit zero-extended number optionally shifted by 12 bits which is a compile-time constant.  `r`, as you know, asks for a general-purpose register.  So if you write any of `atomic_add(1, &c)` or `atomic_add(1+1+1, &c)` or `atomic_add(4095, &c)` or `atomic_add(4096, &c)`, the second line of the `asm` statement will be emitted as immediate `add` instruction, with your constant encoded directly into the instruction: `add w9, w9, #1` and so on.  But if you write `atomic_add(4097, &c)` or `atomic_add(my_variable, &c)`, the compiler will generate additional code before the `asm` to load the appropriate value into some register (say `w13`) and emit `add w9, w9, w13` inside your `asm`.  This lets the compiler generate the more efficient immediate `add` whenever possible, while still getting correct code in general.

Comment: Probably wouldn't hurt to mention that new code might be better served by using the [atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) rather than trying to roll your own with inline asm.  In fact, an argument [can be made](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) not to use inline asm at all...

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Unless it's new code written for the Linux kernel, then it *should* use the existing `atomic_add` function, of course.  But yes, people shouldn't be porting this to their own user-space code, only learning it as a way to understand how the kernel gets the job done.

Comment: Building on what Peter has said, for the Linux kernel in particular, the kernel memory model is *close* but _not quite_ the same as the C11 memory model. See, for example, this 2018 paper exploring some of the differences. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0124r6.html .